# Storing Strings For Later Use In App

Tags: android, temporary

I'm developing an app, after login in, the **JSON response** that comes in, *I need to save a string or the whole response itself*.

Sorry to say, in iOS I know I can save in **plist** and access it later, so I want something similar.

Any option would be appreciated. Thank You

Comment: save it in sharedpreference, use it when required, and then again remove it after you are done with its purpose

Comment: You can use SQLite DB or shared preference

Comment: @YograjShinde using SQLite would require more code

Comment: I read about sharedprefrence @onkar but never did use it before. And didn't know it can hold for that Long. Thought it's just for the main time

Comment: then you can use Shared Preference

Comment: @user3889764 if you want to hold data for long time. DB is better option, as there is some chances you can loose your shared preference data.

Answer (score 0):

Please see:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Or:
[How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)